# Dart `asyncExpand` not working as expected

Tags: dart, stream

I am trying to create the following stream `baz` which consists of an "outer" stream, where each of this stream's events also has an "inner" stream.

For each event X in the outer stream, all the events in the inner stream for X should be added to `baz`.

```dart
class Foo {
  final StreamController<int> bar = StreamController();

  Foo() {
    getsAnOuterStream.listen((event) {
      bar.addStream(getsAnInnerStream(event));
    });
  }

  Stream<int> get baz => bar.stream;
}
```

The above code works as intended. However, I had understood that I could simply achieve this by using the `asyncExpand` [method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-async/Stream/asyncExpand.html) instead.

```dart
class Foo {
  final Stream<int> baz = getsAnOuterStream
    .asyncExpand((event) => getsAnInnerStream(event));
}
```

This does not work – when the outer stream changes, the new inner stream events are not added to `baz`. Is there a subtlety that I'm missing here? Any help is much appreciated!

Just to note... I think the problem could be to do with this: if an inner stream goes on forever, `baz` will never move on to the events from the next inner stream. However, if this is the issue, why does the top solution work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the top code works and the bottom code doesn't is a difference in the implementations of `StreamController.addStream()` ([documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.2/dart-async/StreamController/addStream.html)) and `Stream.asyncExpand()`.

`addStream` listens to the events of the `getsAnInnerStream(event)` stream and just forwards them to `bar`, whereas `asyncExpand` waits for the `getsAnInnerStream(event)` stream to end before moving onto the next `event`.

This means that your code will not work as you expect if the inner streams are open for a long time (or indefinitely).

Comment: This was the problem, it turns out that this can be solved using ReactiveX's merge functionality, see http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks hitecherik for the great explanation and I found a solution, please use [switchMap](https://pub.dev/packages/stream_transform#switchmap-switchlatest) from [stream_transform](https://pub.dev/packages/stream_transform).

> Flatten a Stream of Streams into a Stream which forwards values from the most recent Stream